# Проблема с datatable bootstrap,как это исправить?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, bootstrap

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой,у меня 14000 пользователей в базе данных я создал таблицу в админке с ними через datatable bootstrap при этом таблица очень долго грузит бывает вообще не погружается либо зависает. Когда ставлю лимит на вывод из базы данных до 500 человек сразу всё нормально,как это можно исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте реализовать постраничную загрузку - посмотрите https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать лимитирование в запросе к БД. 
Например:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT {$page*50}, 50
```

Где `$page` номер страницы получаемый например из GET запроса.